# Angular 2 and select placeholder working with formbuilder

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have problem with placeholder in my drop-down list. When I'm using only html code, it works correct. HTML code:

```html
<select  
    class="form-control"
    #selectedItem
    required
    formControlName="town"
>
    <option [ngValue]="undefined" value="undefined" disabled selected>Wybierz miasto</option>
    <option class="city-option">Warszawa</option>
    <option class="city-option">Kraków</option>
    <option class="city-option">Wrocław</option>
</select>
```

The problem is, when I'm trying to put it into formbuilder, the placeholder is disapear. Part of component.ts code

```js
ngOnInit() { 
 this.searchForm = this._formBuilder.group({
  'town': ['tmp']
  });
}
```

How to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value in your `FormGroup` needs to be the same as the value of the option you want to be selected by default:

```js
ngOnInit() { 
  this.searchForm = this._formBuilder.group({
    'town': null
});
```

```html
<option [ngValue]="null" disabled selected>Wybierz miasto</option>
```